# Python Telethon - Get Channel / Chat by its ID

Tags: telethon

I'm using Telethon library (https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon) in order to interact with Telegram API in order to get data posted in the particular channel.

I need to get chat / channel to process at first.

I know that there is a way using **get_dialogs()** - but this is not my case -- I can have new channels / groups to process and I don't want to add group each time to my API account, instead I know ID of new group to process and want to retrieve this group by ID.

But, for some reason, **get_entity()** raises the following error when I'm trying to retrieve chat / channel in which I didn't join, therefore I don't have it in my dialogs.

Does someone know any other way to get channel / chat by its int ID using Telethon library taking into account that I'd potentially need to retrieve channels / chats in which I didn't join?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get access to users, chats or channels by their ID alone, as that would let you enumerate everything and be a privacy risk.

You need to encounter them in the same way you would with an official application, and abide by Telegram's ToS, or risk bans.